# Apache 2.4 using default DocumentRoot instead of VirtualHost DocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, centos7

Long time listener, first time caller...

I've been running Apache for years, and have set up multiple servers.  This one is giving me a hard time and I just can't spot the issue.  I've seen a number of threads here and elsewhere with VirtualHost problems and the wrong DocumentRoot being served, but none of those threads have helped me out.

Server is running Centos 7.5, SELinux enabled, Apache 2.4.33.

I'm wanting to run two VirtualHosts.  For some reason, the secondary VH isn't serving the right files. Changing the order of the VH didn't matter.  Last thing I tried was hard coding a default DocumentRoot (/var/www/html) and then putting each VH in its own separate directory (/var/www/VirtualHost).

Here is my current virtualhost.conf file:

```
#Set a default DocumentRoot
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example2.com
    ServerName example2.com
    ServerAlias www.example2.com
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/example2.com>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example1.com
    ServerName example1.com
    ServerAlias www.example1.com
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/example1.com>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

What I'm seeing in my logs is that all requests are trying to be served from /var/www/html, the default.

I have temporarily changed the log format used so that I can see the ServerName used, and the exact filename being referenced to verify the path.

```
LogFormat "%v %f %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

On the local server, I issue the following two commands to test:

```
wget http://example1.com/index.html
wget http://example2.com/images/logo.jpg
```

My access log shows this:

```
example1.com /var/www/html/index.html 192.168.1.2 - - [18/Jul/2018:11:48:08 -0500] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 208 "-" "Wget/1.14 (linux-gnu)"
example2.com /var/www/html/images 192.168.1.2 - - [18/Jul/2018:11:48:12 -0500] "GET /images/logo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 213 "-" "Wget/1.14 (linux-gnu)"
```

From the log, I can see that the correct domain is showing, but the file path is clearly wrong, Apache is trying to pull the requested files from the default DocumentRoot, and not the DocumentRoot defined for the VirtualHosts, which would have been /var/www/example(x).com.

Output of the httpd -S command as follows:

```
[wright@web2 conf.d]$ httpd -S
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using web2.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server example2.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf:4)
         port 80 namevhost example2.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf:4)
                 alias www.example2.com
         port 80 namevhost example1.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf:17)
                 alias www.example1.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
Mutex lua-ivm-shm: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex cache-socache: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48 not_used
Group: name="apache" id=48 not_used
[wright@web2 conf.d]$
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try not to use Order,Allow,Deny directives and swith to "Require all granted" "Require all denied", etc.... 2.2.x directives has been deprecated for too long and mod_access_compat and those directives should not be used any more nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to resolve my issue, and naturally it had nothing to do with anything I posted above.  Hopefully this will help someone else down the road.

The root cause of my issue turned out to be my installation of PHP 7, specifically with the setup of php-fpm.  The guide I followed suggested creating an fpm.conf file with the following:

```
# PHP scripts setup 
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html

Alias / /var/www/html/
```

Thanks to this config, my DocumentRoot was getting rewritten for all of my VirtualHosts to the above path.  It wasn't until I dumped all of my config files searching for '/var/www' that I came across this file.

Further googling on how to incorporate PHP-FPM with VirtualHosts led me to a page that had this code block within each VirtualHost block:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    # 2.4.10+ can proxy to unix socket
    # SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"

    # Else we can just use a tcp socket:
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
</FilesMatch>
```

Adding this block to both of my VirtualHosts, and removing the old fpm.conf file and restarting Apache resolved my issue, the correct DocumentRoot was now being used for each VHost.  It still remains to be determined if my PHP files are going to be served up correctly, but at least now I'm on the right path.